# Migrating tree structure of graphite

Tags: python, django, graphite

How do we migrate the tree structure of graphite? I tried

```
GET /metrics/index.json
```

which only gives me the graphite tree structure in JSON format. I would however like to display the tree in custom UI.

The desirable output would be:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please show the output and a glimpse of what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz I have updated the view I would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to traverse the /browser/ endpoint and reconstruct it yourself using the node types (e.g. leaf). I have some code in [Descartes](https://github.com/obfuscurity/descartes) that does this already.

https://github.com/obfuscurity/descartes/blob/35e0182664348d3738d348988803b807af3cae73/lib/descartes/public/js/render-graph.js#L71-L107